# angular about SPA , ng-view in ng-view

Tags: angularjs

ng-view  in  ng-view,I get  a  error : inspected target crashed
In  the  index.html, has a  div  with  ng-view

```
<div ng-app="rootscope">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

In the js

```
var rootscope = angular.module('rootscope',['ngRoute','ngTouch']);
    rootscope.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.
            when('/main',{
                templateUrl: 'views/route/main.html',
                controller: 'mainCtrl'
            }).
            when('/',{
                templateUrl: 'views/route/login.html',
                controller: 'indexCtrl'
            }).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }]);
```

controller js

```
rootscope.controller('homeCtrl',function($scope,$location) {
    $scope.login = function(){
        $location.path('/main');
    };
});
```

so first we will  get in  login  view.Then click the login button, should get in main view , in  the main view I want do something like  index.html,div can changed.but, you see my controller js

```
<div id="main">
    <div>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        unchanged
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do i understand correctly that you have nested ng-views, but only a single Angular application set up?

Comment: try to use `data-ng-include` in `main` HTML

Comment: @Sprottenwels you  are  right.I hava no  good  idea for it .

Comment: @Ravi I thought it , I study  angular a  week  ago. I 'm  afraid it's not a good method.